# Laravel - Retrieve Entries Starting with "X"

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search, laravel

I've been looking around and testing things for about 2 hours now, and I finally figured it's time to reach out for help.

Basically, I want to do an search on a catalog - but only return items starting with a specific letter. I've tried multiple things from raw queries, to trying to bend where() to my liking - but none of the existing methods to achieve this has worked for me yet.

The code is rather simple that I'm working with here.

```
$var = DB::('table')->where('field', 'LIKE', "%$argument")->get();
```

$argument is passed via URI (root.com/controller/sort-by/field/$arg). All URI segments print out correctly when dd()'ed. So the proper value is being passed to the query, I would assume? Also if I dd($var), then it populates with the table's entries when I drop out the where() statement.

I've attempted a lot of things here, and nothing is pulling the single entry that I have in the database at the moment...

So, am I'm extremely overlooking something here - or actually tackling this the wrong way?

Comment: Have you tried $var = DB::('table')->where('field', 'LIKE', '%' . $argument)->get(); ?

Comment: or perhaps `["%argument"]` and passing an array to it

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I might need a little bit more understanding of this. I have the arg being passed via the URI - so if I were to turn it into an array, what would that process be? Not really familiar with shoving a single string into an array to access it in a SQL statement.

Comment: So I'm getting some form of response back after changing my query to Table::where('field', 'LIKE', "%$arg"); -- yet I cannot access any of the data from it.

Comment: I swapped the % from the front to the back, and now I'm receiving results - and it does return NULL when not looking for a letter related to the only database entry. Now my issues is that it's returning TWO of the same results, and this is even with ->first()

Answer (score 1):

I swapped my query to

```
$foo = MODEL::where('#FIELD#', 'LIKE', $arg . '%')->get();
```

Then I can access the values by enumerating through the returned array. So a foreach will be required, but in general terms.

```
{{ $foo[0]->field }}
```

Returns the field value.

Thanks all.